# JQuery Simple Combobox (scombobox) get texted string

Tags: jquery, combobox

I have an scombobox and a text field appearing every time the user pressed the `btnAdd` button.

```
$("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
    index++;
    var div = $("<div />");
    div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(''));
    $("#AddContainer").append(div);
    $("#" + index).scombobox({ fullMatch: true });
    var completedField = true; //variable to see if all fields (values ones) are completed - if no not allow to save changes
    //check if each text field for each setting has value
    $("input[name=DynamicTextBox]").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "")
            completedField = false;
    });
    if (completedField == false)
        document.getElementById("AddBtn").disabled = true;
    else
        document.getElementById("AddBtn").disabled = false;
});

$("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
    $(this).closest("div").remove();
    var ddlId = $('[id*=hfDDLId]').val();
    $('[id$=ddl' + parseInt(ddlId) + ']').remove();
    $('[id*=hfDDLId]').val(parseInt($('[id*=hfDDLId]').val()) - 1);
    var previousDropDownId = $('[id*=hfDropDownIds]').val();
    //$('[id*=hfdropdownids]').val(resultids);
    if (document.getElementById("AddContainer").innerHTML == "")
        document.getElementById("AddBtn").disabled = true;
    else {
        var completedField = true; //variable to see if all fields (values ones) are completed - if no not allow to save changes
        //check if each text field for each setting has value
        $("input[name=DynamicTextBox]").each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "")
                completedField = false;
        });
        if (completedField == false)
            document.getElementById("AddBtn").disabled = true;
        else
            document.getElementById("AddBtn").disabled = false;
    }
});

function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {

var combo = $('<select list="' + index + '" name="' + index + '"><datalist style="font-size:150%; width:50%"></select>').attr("id", index).attr("name", index).attr("runat", "server").attr("class", "class combos").attr("required", "required");

$.each(settingsListAry, function (i, el) {
    combo.append("<option value=" + el + ">" + el + "</option>");
});

return '<input type="button" value="-" class="remove btn btn-danger"  style="font-size:75%" />&nbsp'
+ combo.prop('outerHTML') + '&nbsp'
+ '<input name = "DynamicTextBox" class="dtb" type="text" value="' + value + '" required style="line-height: 0; width:30%" onkeyup="allHaveText()"/>'
+ '<div style="clear:both"></div>'
```

}

My problem in that when the user types a new text (not one from the options), when I'm trying to get the typed string `$("#" + i).scombobox('val')` I receive only empty string.

It is possible to get the typed text from the scombobox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem by adding `$("#" + index).scombobox({ fullMatch: true, invalidAsValue: true })` but it seemed that the way I was getting the typed text was working just on IE. In order to `$("#" + i + " .scombobox-display").val()` and it works!

Answer (score 0):

this is the first time I heard of scombobox, there may be better solutions, but check this link http://jsfiddle.net/alpenzoo/7vpf1axs/

```
$("#combo-02").find("input").val()
```

seems to correctly return data from scombobox.